# Struct at overrun error and framing error in USART PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller

I'm trying to communicate PIC18F4550 with biomed module. I'm very new to embedded. My module sends a packet of 5 byte information  **continuously**  at 4800 baud, 1 stop, ODD parity.

I've set my baud rate perfectly BRGH=1, BRG16=1.

My main is:

```
    void main()
{

    INTCON=0xC0;
    RCSTA=0x80;
    TXSTA=0x24;
    BAUDCON=0x08;
    PIE1bits.RCIE=1;
    IPR1bits.RCIP=1;
    SPBRGH=0x09;
    SPBRG=0xC3;
    RCSTAbits.CREN=1;
}
```

My ISR is:

```
    void uart_isr(void)
{
    if(PIR1bits.RCIF=1)

    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
            PORTD=RCREG;
      if(RCSTAbits.OERR) 
        { PORTBbits.RB6=~PORTBbits.RB6;
          do{ 
            temp = RCREG; 
            temp = RCREG; 
            temp = RCREG; 
            RCSTAbits.CREN = 0; 
            RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; 
          }while(RCSTAbits.OERR); 
    } 

            PORTD=PORTD-32;
            buff[i]=PORTD;
            myMsDelay(15);

        }   

 }
}
```

I'm getting lots of overrun. Please suggest some method to stop these errors.

Comment: There's no { after the if statement and you have an extra } at the end. Are you sure you have copied the code correctly?

Comment: Is there a gap between packets? How are they delimited?

Comment: Forget trying to receive 32 characters inside your ISR. You have nothing to time reading the buffer with the actual reception of any characters other than the first. Receive a single character, put it in a buffer, increment an index pointer to point to the next buffer location, and exit (until the next interrupt). You can flag your main loop to process the buffer once it is filled. And follow Dan's advice and get rid of the delay.

Comment: You could probably make this work if you added: while(!RCIF) {}; before the PORTD=RCREG; line and get rid of the myMsDelay(15); line  ... It would be better to follow the advice from my previous comment as you would then not be stuck waiting around for 32 characters to come in.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the totality of the root cause, but these are definitely problems in your code:

> if(PIR1bits.RCIF=1)

That's the classic assignment-vs-comparison-operator error. I'm sure you meant `==` instead of `=`.

> myMsDelay(15);

A delay inside of an interrupt routine is a big no-no. You're already blocking your regular code flow since you're in the ISR. Now, you're delaying for 15ms within the ISR, which is blocking even the ISR itself from running. My guess is that's probably why you're getting overruns. The code is spinning on that delay while new characters are arriving on the buffer. But your ISR can't service them because it's stuck in that delay function.